# Elasticsearch: Sort After Aggregation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index like below:

```
{
  "srcMac": "00:18:7d:d5:7f:03",
  "dstMac": "00:a0:1e:14:0b:15",
  "srcIp": "172.20.99.11",
  "dstIp": "172.20.11.21",
  "srcPort": "38252",
  "dstPort": "102",
  "protocol": "mms",
  "groupKey": "00:18:7d:d5:7f:03#00:a0:1e:14:0b:15#172.20.99.11#172.20.11.21#38252#102#mms",
  "length": 287,
  "createTime": 1640363400229,
  "startTime": 1640275200000,
  "endTime": 1640361599999
}
```

mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "createTime": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "dstIp": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "dstMac": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "dstPort": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "endTime": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "groupKey": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "length": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "protocol": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "srcIp": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "srcMac": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "srcPort": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        },
        "startTime": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to aggregate by multi fields : **[srcMac, dstMac, srcIp, dstIp, srcPort, dstPort, protocol]**, so I add a field "**groupKey**" and then aggregate by it.

My query is :

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {...},
  "aggregations": {
    "aggTotal": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "groupKey"
      }
    },
    "grouping": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "groupKey",
        "size": 50,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "order": [
          {
            "sendTimeMax": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "lengthMin": {
          "min": {
            "field": "length"
          }
        },
        "lengthMax": {
          "max": {
            "field": "length"
          }
        },
        "lengthAvg": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "length"
          },
          "sendTimeMax": {
            "max": {
              "field": "startTime"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to sort by **srcIp** or **dstIp**, **srcMac**, **dstMac** after aggragation, but the data after aggragation don't have the field srcIp, what can I do to sort after aggragation.

Comment: If your `groupKey` was `[srcIp, dstIp, srcMac, dstMac, ...]` you would be able to sort by the bucket key. Would that solve?

Comment: but I also need to sort by dstIp, srcMac, dstMac

Comment: Can you tell what data type you have configured for `*Mac` and `*Ip`?

Comment: They are all keyword. I add the mapping to my question now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html)  on `groupKey` instead of aggregations, then sorting etc will work properly. It might return unexpected results though if your query matches more than `size` docs so be careful.

Comment: I need to calculate the MIN and MAX of field "length" in each group, could this be done use collapse?

Comment: You can get one of those by sorting by `length` if you don't need another sort. Otherwise you'll need both aggs and collapse.